# Make Apollo Client Auto Update Cache By Watching ID

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, shopify-api

I try to setup a Shopify store using Next.js with the Apollo Client.  I just wonder what the easiest method would be to make the cart component refetch the items from the cart whenever I put a new item in the cart (in another component).  The two queries in question are the following:

```
query ($id: ID!) {
    node(id: $id) {
        id
        ... on Checkout {
            lineItems(first: 250) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        title
                        quantity
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the cart component and

```
mutation checkoutLineItemsAdd(
    $lineItems: [CheckoutLineItemInput!]!
    $checkoutId: ID!
) {
    checkoutLineItemsAdd(lineItems: $lineItems, checkoutId: $checkoutId) {
        checkout {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

in the product component.

The Apollo documentation says

> If a mutation updates a single existing entity, Apollo Client can automatically update that entity's value in its cache when the mutation returns. To do so, the mutation must return the id of the modified entity, along with the values of the fields that were modified. Conveniently, mutations do this by default in Apollo Client.

and I wonder if the checkout ID could somehow be used to initiate this behaviour in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I had to include the cached information in the mutation query, like this:

```
mutation checkoutLineItemsAdd(
    $lineItems: [CheckoutLineItemInput!]!
    $checkoutId: ID!
) {
    checkoutLineItemsAdd(lineItems: $lineItems, checkoutId: $checkoutId) {
        checkout {
            id
            lineItems(first: 250) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        title
                        quantity
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```